# Installation of olace-pubsubplus using pip

Tags: solace

I want to use solace-pubsubplus python api.So I am trying to install solace-pubsubplus in ubuntu:20:04 but I am getting following error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement solace-pubsubplus==1.5.0 (from versions: 0.2.0, 0.2.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for solace-pubsubplus==1.5.0

can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using docker and building docker image from mac. So I had to use --platform while building and running docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check that you are trying to run it in a Supported Environment:  https://docs.solace.com/API/API-Developer-Guide/Supported-Environments.htm#Python

In your case the x86_64 might be tripping you up:

> Linux variants with Linux 2.6 (x86_64) or later

Answer (score 0):

And please make sure you have the latest version of pip
`pip install --upgrade pip`